# Localization of vscode extension webviews, fsPath vs contents

Tags: visual-studio-code, localization, vscode-extensions

I've been tasked with localizing a vscode extension with webviews. I do this by reading the file at vscode.l10n.uri?.fsPath, then sending the contents of that file to the webview like so:

```
panel.webview.postMessage({
   command: 'sendLocalization',
   contents: fileContents
});
```

In the webview I import the l10n library
`import * as l10n from '@vscode/l10n';`
then I have a window.addEventListener which listens for that message, and when it receives it I do:

```
l10n.config({
   contents: fileContents
});
```

This works and my webview is localized. However, according to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vscode/l10n) I should be able to set the path rather than the contents, like this:

```
l10n.config({
   fsPath: filePath // filePath = vscode.l10n.uri?.fsPath
});
```

I'd prefer to do it that way because it seems easier and more efficient. However it doesn't work for me, the strings in my webview remain in English when I do it. When I do console.log(vscode.l10n.uri?.fsPath) in the webview, it does correctly display the file path, and the file definitely exists at that spot. What am I doing wrong? I am new to vscode/nodejs/javascript so I'm probably missing something obvious.